# CSS to make something in next line in align with above line

Tags: html, css

I am facing an issue, the text in next line is starting right beneath from Icon.  But i want that text shall start right beneath under above line of text.

It is appearing as below:

[image]

But it shall look like this

[image]

HTML for above markup is

```
<div class="column selected-category-label small-7 medium-9">
   <span id="image" class="label-image"><svg class="icon icon-418" 
    focusable="false"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    xlink:href="#icon-418"></use></svg>&nbsp;</span>
   <span id="category" class="label-category">Lewn og gwld</span>
</div>
```

CSS markup is

```
.selected-category-label .icon {
height: 2.5rem;
width: 2.5rem;
stroke: #012F60;
fill: #012F60;
top: 0.3125rem;
position: relative;}

.selected-category-label .icon {
  margin-left: -0.625rem;
  margin-top: -1.25rem;
}
```

Comment: you can either use the `img` as `background` and give `padding-left` to the wrapper OR use different containers for both `img` as well as the *text*.

Comment: when i use different containers then there is very much white space between those. like i tried using `<div class="small-1"><img></div><div class="small-11">Text></div>`

Comment: @Gags Are you looking for something like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/g861L0w1/3) ?

Comment: is that length of text static ????

Comment: nop. text can be of any length

Comment: @Gags are you using any css frameworks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help.  Use two inline block level containers and declare the margin on one so as to set the distance between them.

```css
#image {
  display:inline-block;
  height:30px;
  width:100px;
  background: silver;
  }
#category {
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:5px;
  text-align:left;
  vertical-align:top;
  width:70px;
  font-size:20px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="column selected-category-label small-7 medium-9">
   <div id="image" class="label-image"></div>
   <div id="category" class="label-category">Lewn ogasdasdas gwldasdasdasdasd</div>
</div>
```

Comment: is width to image and category is necessary?

Comment: @Gags no, it doesn't. This is a very good solution without floats, that avoid to break your layout. Test it, I'm sure that you solve your issue :)

Comment: No, the width is not required - just the margin to keep the blocks apart.  The widths can be set by the content.  Or you can set the widths if that suits your layout.

Comment: check this works for long string also but its coming on new line after specific length

Comment: @saurabh2836 - this still works in your proposed edit.  Where have you seen it break?

Comment: @sideroxylon ... on small screens it has issues.. text and image are on diff lines :(

Comment: @Gags - just re-set the widths to be percentages of the screen width (or container if they are both in a container).  And set overflow to hidden or scroll.

Comment: yup.. i was thinking so

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way of achieving this (apart from the `inline-block` approach, mentioned above) is to use flexbox. If you just add the rule:

```
.selected-category-label {
  display:flex;
}
```

...then the `.selected-category-label` container becomes a flex container, and the two spans inside it will be flex items, which should behave the way you require.

Comment: but flex is not supported in all browsers

Comment: Flex is now [very widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) - by almost all browsers other than IE8/9. And those browsers will just have the text wrap, which is not necessarily a disaster!

Comment: Bear in mind you can mix flexbox with other approaches, so you could still use inline-block to catch older browsers, but use flex to get the better height-handling that comes with that.

Answer (score -2):

Would something like this work?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span id="image" class="label-image"><svg class="icon icon-418" 
focusable="false"</td>
    <td valign="bottom">Lewn og </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td valign="top">gwld</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: text is getting generated at run time. this can niot work

Comment: Also, <table> should be used for marking up tables / tabular data, not for layout.